# Get image from post in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, widget

I need to configure this script so that it fetches the first image that is in the article and shows it in a widjet.

At the moment the widjet only shows featured images, I would like it to show external images that were in the post.

For example, the first image in the article would be shown.

Code

```
<?php
/**
 * Featured Posts widget
 */

class colormag_featured_posts_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops  = array(
            'classname'                   => 'widget_featured_posts widget_featured_meta',
            'description'                 => __( 'Display latest posts or posts of specific category.', 'colormag' ),
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        );
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 250 );
        parent::__construct( false, $name = __( 'TG: Featured Posts (Style 1)', 'colormag' ), $widget_ops );
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        $tg_defaults['title']    = '';
        $tg_defaults['text']     = '';
        $tg_defaults['number']   = 4;
        $tg_defaults['type']     = 'latest';
        $tg_defaults['category'] = '';
        $instance                = wp_parse_args( ( array ) $instance, $tg_defaults );
        $title                   = esc_attr( $instance['title'] );
        $text                    = esc_textarea( $instance['text'] );
        $number                  = $instance['number'];
        $type                    = $instance['type'];
        $category                = $instance['category'];
        ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Layout will be as below:', 'colormag' ) ?></p>
        <div style="text-align: center;"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/style-1.jpg' ?>">
        </div>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'colormag' ); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php _e( 'Description', 'colormag' ); ?>
        <textarea class="widefat" rows="5" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'text' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'text' ); ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></textarea>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to display:', 'colormag' ); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="radio" <?php checked( $type, 'latest' ) ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'type' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'type' ); ?>" value="latest" /><?php _e( 'Show latest Posts', 'colormag' ); ?>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" <?php checked( $type, 'category' ) ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'type' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'type' ); ?>" value="category" /><?php _e( 'Show posts from a category', 'colormag' ); ?>
            <br /></p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Select category', 'colormag' ); ?>
                :</label>
            <?php wp_dropdown_categories( array(
                'show_option_none' => ' ',
                'name'             => $this->get_field_name( 'category' ),
                'selected'         => $category,
            ) ); ?>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance          = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        if ( current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ) {
            $instance['text'] = $new_instance['text'];
        } else {
            $instance['text'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes( $new_instance['text'] ) ) );
        }
        $instance['number']   = absint( $new_instance['number'] );
        $instance['type']     = $new_instance['type'];
        $instance['category'] = $new_instance['category'];

        return $instance;
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        extract( $instance );

        global $post;
        $title    = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
        $text     = isset( $instance['text'] ) ? $instance['text'] : '';
        $number   = empty( $instance['number'] ) ? 4 : $instance['number'];
        $type     = isset( $instance['type'] ) ? $instance['type'] : 'latest';
        $category = isset( $instance['category'] ) ? $instance['category'] : '';

        $post_status = 'publish';
        if ( get_option( 'fresh_site' ) == 1 ) {
            $post_status = array( 'auto-draft', 'publish' );
        }

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'      => $number,
            'post_type'           => 'post',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'no_found_rows'       => true,
            'post_status'         => $post_status,
        );

        // Display from category chosen.
        if ( $type == 'category' ) {
            $args['category__in'] = $category;
        }

        $get_featured_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

        echo $before_widget;
        ?>
        <?php
        if ( $type != 'latest' ) {
            $border_color = 'style="border-bottom-color:' . colormag_category_color( $category ) . ';"';
            $title_color  = 'style="background-color:' . colormag_category_color( $category ) . ';"';
        } else {
            $border_color = '';
            $title_color  = '';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
            echo '<h3 class="widget-title" ' . $border_color . '><span ' . $title_color . '>' . esc_html( $title ) . '</span></h3>';
        }
        if ( ! empty( $text ) ) {
            ?> <p> <?php echo esc_textarea( $text ); ?> </p> <?php } ?>
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        while ( $get_featured_posts->have_posts() ):$get_featured_posts->the_post();
            ?>

            <?php if ( $i == 1 ) {
                $featured = 'colormag-featured-post-medium';
            } else {
                $featured = 'colormag-featured-post-small';
            } ?>


            <?php if ( $i == 1 ) {
                echo '<div class="first-post">';
            } elseif ( $i == 2 ) {
                echo '<div class="following-post">';
            } ?>


            <div class="single-article clearfix">


                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $image           = '';
                    $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
                    $image_alt_text  = get_post_meta( $thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
                    $title_attribute = get_the_title( $post->ID );
                    if ( empty( $image_alt_text ) ) {
                        $image_alt_text = $title_attribute;
                    }
                    $image .= '<figure>';
                    $image .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title( '', '', false ) . '">';
                    $image .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, $featured, array(
                            'title' => esc_attr( $title_attribute ),
                            'alt'   => esc_attr( $image_alt_text ),
                        ) ) . '</a>';
                    $image .= '</figure>';
                    echo $image;
                }
                ?>


                <div class="article-content">
                    <?php colormag_colored_category(); ?>
                    <h3 class="entry-title">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h3>
                    <div class="below-entry-meta">
                        <?php
                        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
                        if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
                            $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
                        }
                        $time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
                            esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
                            esc_html( get_the_date() ),
                            esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
                            esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
                        );
                        printf( __( '<span class="posted-on"><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> %3$s</a></span>', 'colormag' ), esc_url( get_permalink() ), esc_attr( get_the_time() ), $time_string
                        );
                        ?>
                        <span class="byline"><span class="author vcard"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_author() ); ?></a></span></span>
                        <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && comments_open() ) { ?>
                            <span class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i><?php comments_popup_link( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ( $i == 1 ) { ?>
                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>

            </div>
            <?php if ( $i == 1 ) {
                echo '</div>';
            } ?>
            <?php
            $i ++;
        endwhile;
        if ( $i > 2 ) {
            echo '</div>';
        }
        // Reset Post Data
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        <!-- </div> -->
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

}
```

This is the complete code of the widget

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
  <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
  <div id="custom-bg" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">

  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me, I added the code to the theme and it had no effect. I think there is a way to do that but so far I haven't found any.